# Is there a way to inset a border to the height of an object?

Tags: css, object, height, border

I'm working on a project to controll machines using a website and i'm currently working on the css stylesheet. 
I've got this script right now:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Machine overview V1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
<h1>Machine overview</h1>
</header>
    <section>
</section>
    <footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

now lets say that:

```
header{height:15%;width:100%;}
section{height:80%;width:100%;}
footer{height:5%;width:100%;}
```

But when you add a

```
border:1px solid black;
```

to any of these attributes it messes up the height in %,
which basicly messes up the whole layout of the page.
I can't force the height in npx becouse it has to look good using different resolutions.
**Is there a way to inset a border to the height of an object?**
just like you can inset box-shadow...

Answer (score 1):

You want to set your container to `box-sizing:border-box;`

```
.borderInside {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: You should always put the unprefixed one last. Current versions of Chrome and Safari support box-sizing without a prefix. They also support it prefixed and they'll use whichever you write last - in this case the prefixed one.